# Why won't this PHP script strip the BOM from a file?

Tags: php, byte-order-mark

I've tried everything I can think of (including notepad++, which would not work for me although it appears others have better luck).

I've some very old Access databases (I mean from the mid/late 1990s created using Visual Basic 4) which I'm converting to Web Apps (PHP, Javascript etc using a lot of AJAX).

I've an old copy of Access2000 which despite a myriad of errors does actually still work under Windows 10 with some persuasion; which I'm using to export data with.

What I have a slight problem with is encoding.  I'm trying to export as UTF8 to try and avoid diamonds with ? marks in them.  Access has a UFT8 export setting but it puts a BOM (FFFE) at the start of the file(s); which messes things up a bit.

Simple question: why does not the following work? Well, actually, it works but it strips the first 2 bytes after the BOM and leavs the BOM in place.

It's nothing I can't work round so no sweat; just wondering.

```
<?php
$h = fopen("test.txt", "rb");
$w = fopen("fixed.txt", "wb");

$r = fread($h, "2");
do{
  $r = fread($h, "1");
  fwrite($w, $r); 
} while (!feof($h));

fclose($h);
?>
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data.

Comment: Why is your byte count in double quotes? It is surely just a number.

Comment: I don't see that posting a hex dump with 0xFFFE as the first 2 bytes shines much light on the matter.  Correct, fread's count should be a number (makes no difference as php is loosely typed). The 'problem' I think is that php itself respects the BOM and, TBF, it should not under the above circumstances. Guess I'll have to resort to gcc.

Comment: @Nagi So you are claiming that Microsoft software wrote a file where the contents have been encoded in UTF8, but that is prefixed with a two-byte UTF16 BOM, not a 3-byte UTF8 pseudo-BOM?? Sure the data is not encoded in UTF16_LE??

Comment: My mistake. I was aware but not 'up' on UTF prior to my current project (just used UTF8 and let things go as they please). Access has a multitude of code page exports: I chose simple UTF assuming I'd get 'standard' UTF, I now realise that UTF here equates to UFT16. Anyway, I was actually more interested in PHP's fread function not doing what I expected.